# CSS still can't align hyper link with bottom-left of window

Tags: html, css

I'm just trying to make a hyperlink (which is the div `.t2`) appear in the bottom left corner, and I'm assuming it has something to do with the dimensions of the body, but I can't figure it out.

my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <title> Incident Report Page </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://....">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
    Incident Report Page    
</div>

<div class="t1">
<form action="connect_database.php" method=post >
<p>
username   <input type="text"   name = "un"> <br><br>
password   <input type="password" name = "pw"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name = "subby" value = "Enter">
</p>
</form>
</div>

<div class="t2">
    <p><b><a href="http://....">HTTP exchanges</a></b></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS is:

```
body {
    font-family: Century Gothic, Arial;
    background-color: #836FFF; 
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.t2 {
     position: absolute;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
} 
.header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 910px;
    background-color: #6A5ACD;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #473C8B;
    text-align: center;
}
.t1 {
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto; 
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #473C8B; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: So explain the exact problem.  It's not close enough to the edge?  It's in the opposite corner?  Or what?

Comment: It is somewhere in the middle left of the page

Comment: Thank you sir, but I'm curious why it was in the middle of the page even though I tried to set it to the bottom left.

Comment: Because that's where the bottom of the "page/document" is.  You really want it at the bottom of the "viewport".  It may not be a bad idea to study about various `div` layout techniques... I think you would be better off enclosing everything in a wrapper `div`, giving you more control moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it fixed in the bottom/left corner of the viewport, then simply change `.t2` to `position:fixed;`

```
.t2 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Here is a Demo...

http://jsfiddle.net/h2qFU/